# How to Add ajax form processing for html mail form

Tags: javascript, ajax, contact-form, ajaxform

I currently finished creating ( modify a themeforest template ) a website and all i need to do now is to set up contact form to receive mail from my customers

```
 /* *****************************************************************
 * FORM VALIDATION
 * ************************************************************** */

$("#contactForm").validate({
    rules: {
        fullname: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fullname: {
            required: "Please enter your name"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        message: "Please enter your message"
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        // Add your ajax form processing here.
    }
});
```

This is the code form config.js file. How do i set up with my mail ( contact@website.com )

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server side programming language. Step 2: Learn how to send email with it. Step 3: Adapt your code from step two to support user input from a form submission. Step 4: Consider adding client side validation to the form (i.e. the code in your question). Step 5: Consider enhancing it with Ajax.  (For all steps: Do some basic research and read some tutorials before coming to Stackoverflow. Your question is currently way too broad and you should expect it to be closed.)

Comment: $.ajax({
       url : "sendEmail.php",
       type: "POST",
       data : {"key": "value"},
       beforeSend: function() {
       },
       success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
          }
      });

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'contact.php', data:$('#contactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) { $('#contactForm').find('.form-control').html(response);}});
```

this is the final syntax that works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var data = new FormData($("#contactForm")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url : 'your url ',
    type : 'post',
    data : data,
    mimeType    : 'multipart/form-data'
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){

    }

});
```